# Puppeteer how to log list of object from map based on elementsArray get via $()

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a simple script in puppeteer that should log a list of created objects in the map method.

```js
const getFilteredOrders = async (page, pagesToFilter, error, paymentMethod, affiliationName) => {
    const { base, orders } = config.URL;
    const { tableRow, reservationNumber, affiliation, url } = config.elements.orders;

    await page.goto(`${base}${orders}`);
    const rows = await page.$$(tableRow);

    const tt = rows.map( async row => {
        const aff = await row.$(affiliation);
        const reservation = await row.$(reservationNumber);
        const urlOrder = await row.$(url);
        
        return {
            affiliation: await aff.evaluate(aff => aff.innerText),
            error: await reservation.evaluate(reservation => reservation.innerText.trim() === "error" ? true : false),
            order: await urlOrder.evaluate(urlOrder => urlOrder.getAttribute('href'))
        }
    });

    console.log(await tt);
};
```

console.log shows me a list of promises, but I except a list of created objects.

When I wrap the object in the map method with console.log it shows me objects that I want to have into the array.

Comment: Why you need async await in page.$$(tableRow)?

Comment: Try it by yourself. it is just a dumb question. Without async You will get undefined :)

Comment: I think you have too much async and await in your function

Comment: Yup, cuz I was trying to figure it out but I also think that you have no idea how to solve my problem, so take your time :D

Answer (score 0):

Method `.map` by itself does not suit well for async data as it does not wait for callbaks' completion. You can heip it with `Promise.all()` or use `for-of` loop:

```js
const tt = await Promise.all(rows.map(async (row) => {
  // ...
}));
```

Or:

```js
const tt = [];
for (const row of rows) {
  // ...
  tt.push({
    affiliation: await aff.evaluate(aff => aff.innerText),
    error: await reservation.evaluate(reservation => reservation.innerText.trim() === "error" ? true : false),
    order: await urlOrder.evaluate(urlOrder => urlOrder.getAttribute('href'))
  });
}
```